# First time making my drag and drop FileReader() event but can't read the content of the file

Tags: javascript, text, filereader

Hi I need help on how I can make my drag and drop read the .text files that is dropped in the dropzone.. I'm still exploring javascript and would need help to guide me on what is wrong with my code..

The content of the text file should be shown on the **displayarea**

Reference: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Thanks in advance!

https://jsfiddle.net/d6nur0wc/1/

```
 (function() {
   var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");

  dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.className = "dropzone";

    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);

    window.onload = function() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('dropzone');
      var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('displayarea');

      fileInput.addEventListener('dropzone.ondrop', function(read) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(read) {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
          }

          reader.readAsText(file);
          }

          else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
          }
      });
  }
  }

  dropzone.ondragover = function() {
    this.className = "dropzone dragover";
    return false;
  };

  dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
    this.className = "dropzone";
    return false;
  };

  }())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this. you have to remove `onload` event listener. it can't be compatible here.

```
(function() {
  var dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");

  dropzone.ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.className = "dropzone";

    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);


      var fileInput = document.getElementById('dropzone');
      var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('displayarea');

        var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
        var textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function(read) {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
          }

          reader.readAsText(file);
          }

          else {
            fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!";
          }
}

  dropzone.ondragover = function() {
    this.className = "dropzone dragover";
    return false;
  };

  dropzone.ondragleave = function() {
    this.className = "dropzone";
    return false;
  };

}())
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I removed that block of code. However, it still wont show the reader.result

Comment: I tested that on jsfiddle and it reads the contents of txt file.